# Get the respective button value in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

once I add a group of dynamic buttons from an array and the querySelectorAll doesn't seem to get the list of buttons.
Here my code: Where am I going wrong?

```js
const btns = document.getElementById("container");
const textBtn = ["btn 1", "btn 2", "btn 3", "btn 4", "btn 5", "btn 6"]
for (i = 0; i < textBtn.length; i++) {
  btns.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<button  class="allbuttons" value=${textBtn[i]}>${textBtn[i]}</button>`);
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".allbuttons")
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    //console.log( btn[i]);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    alert(event.target.value)
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure your code is correct. Where do you set the .allbuttons CSS class ? I can't see it.

Comment: @ Emmanuel Demey, sorry for the mess, it's my first post and I'm kind of lost, but I've edited the post

Comment: I added your code in a snippet. You can edit your post and click "edit the above snippet", because your code lacks the buttons. There are no elements that have the class `.allbuttons`.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me, I already put the missing part, but I can't get the value of the respective button, I only get "btn" and not corresponding

Comment: @MauricioRios Right click on one of the buttons and select "Inspect", and see where the numbers are. You need to wrap your class in "quotes", because you got a space between _btn_ and the _number_ and the number will be an attribute instead of part of the class.

Comment: Taking this opportunity, I have one more question.
How do I change the background color of the clicked button? I tried this but got an error:
btn[i].style.background="#ff5353"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does it help? is it what u need?

```js
const btns = document.getElementById("container");
const textBtn = ["btn 1", "btn 2", "btn 3", "btn 4", "btn 5", "btn 6"]
for (i = 0; i < textBtn.length; i++) {
  btns.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type="button" class="allbuttons" value="${textBtn[i]}">`);
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".allbuttons")
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    alert(event.target.value)
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may come from this:
`<button class="allbuttons" value=${textBtn[i]}>${textBtn[i]}</button>`

Your value isn't between quotes `<button class="allbuttons" value="${textBtn[i]}">${textBtn[i]}</button>`